# Simple function to find maximum value up to each position in an array?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose we have the following data frame and we wish to find the maximum of column 'value' up to each row, i.e. the resulting new column should be `c(4993, 4993, 5036, 5036, 5036)`. Of course I can write a loop for this, but just wondering is there a simple dplyr solution as loops can get tedious to read?

```
> myDf[1:5, ]
        time value
1 2018-01-03  4993
2 2018-01-15    52
3 2018-08-02  5036
4 2018-08-17  -162
5 2018-09-05  4806
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The `cummax` function is built in for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the built-in function `cummax`:

```r
set.seed(641032)
x <- rnorm(10)
x
#>  [1]  0.91326263  1.29385203  1.39573077  0.02985411  0.11766056 -1.15891724
#>  [7] -1.02509101 -0.31448858 -0.06675214 -1.34341847
cummax(x)
#>  [1] 0.9132626 1.2938520 1.3957308 1.3957308 1.3957308 1.3957308 1.3957308
#>  [8] 1.3957308 1.3957308 1.3957308
```